# finding primes in the interval [2n, 3n]

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, computational-mathematics

What should I input to the python programming language so I can find prime numbers in the intervals [2n,3n]. I want a shortcut one since n is up to 945. It is for my thesis.

Comment: With $n$ that small, you can just as easily just store  a table of the primes up to $3000$. If did you mean primes with up to $945$ digits?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : However, I have to check if there is at least one prime exist in every n. Say for example, n=5. That means , I have to check the primes between [10, 15]. And I will do that up to n=945.

Comment: Right, so list all primes in order up to 3000. Then when given an $n$, use binary search to find the first prime $\geq 2n$ and then walk the list until you find a prime $>3n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ok thanks. I'll give it a try.